# How to use kamon system metrics without creating a shaded jar

Tags: java, akka, monitoring, grafana

Im currently trying to show System+Jvm metrics within a Grafana Dashboard, one option to gather these metrics is to use the kamon dependencies @ http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.kamon
However whenever i attempt to run my jar i get an error although the build process is fine. The error relates to

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'kamon.metric'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
```

I have solved this problem by creating a shaded jar, as outlined in the akka docs http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html.
It seems the problem with not merging all of the reference.confs and the defaults being lost. However the creation of a shaded jar seems overkill for what is required.

Has anyone else found a nicer solution to this?

Thanks
Jake